# Intel Thread Building Blocks alternatives & licensing

Tags: c++, multithreading, licensing, tbb

**Before you mark this question as a duplicate please take in to consideration that most of the similar questions are 5+ years old!**

I have two questions:

1. The dual-licensing. What does it mean?! Would I have to buy the [commercial version](https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-tbb) to make a commercial closed-source project?

At [this page](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download), it says that

> Intel® TBB is offered commercially for customers who want the additional support that comes with Intel® Premier Support.  **The commercial version is also available for developers who cannot follow the GPLv2 with the runtime exception license**. - See more at: https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/download#sthash.YjVMDqhv.dpuf

But in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/403299/3409611) he says that the only advantage of buying it, is that you get support. Please notice this question is 7 years old, and therefore I can't trust it, as things could have changed.

2. If I can't use TBB for a closed-source commercial project, what are som alternatives? I will most likely only need features like concurrent maps and queues.

**Edit:** Also if the commercial version is required, could I wait buying it till release of my app?

Comment: Have you read the licenseof TBB  ? What is unclear about it ?

Comment: @nos It doesn't make any sense to me calling it a commercial version, if it's actually only support. Better safe than sorry. I've also read that you can't include it in your executable if not having the commercial version.

Comment: Well, that's why you have to read the license, so you know what it covers, what you can do , and what applies to your particular situation.

Comment: @nos Unfortunately I'm not a lawyer, and it doesn't make it easier to understand when it's "dual-licensed"

Comment: Asking software engineers for legal advice sounds like a great way to get yourself in serious legal trouble.

Comment: Can you comply with GPL licensed version? If yes, full stop. Do that.

Comment: @Jeff I won't make the source-code public, so I guess I can't comply with the GPL license. Nor can I afford such an expensive piece of software.

Comment: Look at Intel Nest. I think TBB commercial license is free now. https://software.intel.com/sites/campaigns/nest/ -> https://registrationcenter.intel.com/en/forms/?productid=2558&licensetype=2

Answer (score 1):

Re: #2 (TBB alternatives), if you're on Windows, the [PPL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492418.aspx) provides parallel containers and algorithms that are somewhat [source compatible](https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/appendices/ppl_compatibility.htm) with TBB.

Also, [Boost.Lockfree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/doc/html/lockfree.html) has lock-free queue and stack implementations.

If you need parallel algorithms and don't mind being on the bleeding edge, take a look at [HPX](http://stellar-group.org/libraries/hpx/) as an alternative to TBB. It's under very active development, though, so it might be a bit of a moving target... In their latest 0.9.11 release they've implemented some aspects of the [Parallelism TS](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2015/n4505.pdf), so there might be some API stability there that could make you (somewhat) well positioned to transition to standard algorithms if those ever materialize. Relevant docs are [here](http://stellar-group.github.io/hpx/docs/html/hpx/manual/parallel/parallel_algorithms.html).